# tabla en html con datos sql

Tags: javascript, java, html, html5, html-tabla

Necesito generar una tabla en html con datos que traigo de una tabla sql.
Lo puedo realizar con un simple out.print, aunque no queda bien distribuido en la pagina.
Hay alguna forma de ingresar datos desde SQL a una table?
Este es el código que genero

```
int resultado=0;
      
       
      String qry = ("SELECT * FROM datos");
      
      try{
          Statement st = conex.createStatement();
          ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(qry);
          
          while(rs.next()){
              resultado=1;
            if(resultado==1){
                String comprador = rs.getString("comprador");
                String fecha = rs.getString("fecha");
                Double total = rs.getDouble("total");
                
                out.print("Comprador Total Fecha");
                out.print("<br>"+comprador+" "+total+" "+fecha+"<br><br>");
                
            }  
          }
      }catch(Exception e){
          out.print("Error de conexion" + e);
      }
```

Comment: `Hay alguna forma de ingresar datos desde SQL a una table?` Simplemente genera el HTML correspondiente a una tabla HTML. ¿Cuál es la dificultad?

Comment: El problema es que no entiendo como ingresar los datos sacados de sql. Hay algún ejemplo para poder tomar de referencia?

Comment: Como estas usando java mira esto -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15444982/how-to-display-or-print-the-contents-of-a-database-table-as-is